# Название курса — приложение или нет?

Tags: приложение

Публикация этой повести в Вашем журнале породила новый курс для студентов УПИ (УГТУ) 2016 года «Планетарные передачи грузоподъемных машин» на основе ее разрезов (чертежей)...

Считается ли название курса *«Планетарные передачи грузоподъемных машин»* приложением и нужно ли его выделять двумя запятыми или двумя тире?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выделение здесь  не требуется.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: А если так: УРАЛЬСКИЙ ПОЛИТЕХ (УГТУ УПИ) ВВЕЛ НОВЫЙ СПЕЦКУРС ДЛЯ СТУДЕНТОВ В 2016 ГОДУ —
«ПЛАНЕТАРНЫЕ ПЕРЕДАЧИ ГРУЗОПОДЪЕМНЫХ МАШИН», то тире требуется или оно необязательно?

Comment: Здесь тире ставится.

Comment: Спасибо еще раз!